# Problems with network services on ubuntu 23.04

Tags: networking

I have a laptop running ubuntu 23.04 with kernel 6.2.0 and gnome 44.1, with the following services: ftpd, telentd, httpd, samba, xrdp. Up until two weeks ago, everything was fine, meaning I was able to access all services from the LAN.

Two weeks ago, I discovered that ports 21, 80, 139, 3389 cannot be accessed from the LAN while locally they are open. I mean I can use ftp or firefox to access the laptop locally, but not from the LAN. Only telent still works from the LAN.

It looks to me as if somehow a firewall  was installed at some point that blocks these ports; but i am not aware nor i can find anything to that regard.

Can some one please help me trouble shoot his problem....

thank you

Comment: Try `ufw status`, read `man ufw`, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW